# Handling diacritics in SIP headers

Tags: sip, diacritics

Following the SIMPLE specification of OMA, when sending a SIP INVITE for chat we can use a header named Subject.
Typically, this header contains the first message sent by a user to his contact.

My question is: this message can contain diacritics, so how should I encode them? Is there a standard definition on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode them as UTF-8 as specified in the [SIP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt). There are a few SIP Headers where UTF-8 is not allowed and US ASCII with escaping rules is mandated but the Subject header is not one of those.